# Please notify users when their comment is deleted

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-comments

I recently was on a highly downvoted question where the user posted a huge code dump and said something along the lines of:

> This is for an assignment, and I really don't have time to do it right now, so if you'd help me out you'd be really amazing!

(I would find the question for you, but apparently it's been deleted; at least, I can't find anything from it in my "Activity" tab.)

Under this, I posted a comment that said "Everyone has time: " followed by a YouTube clip.  I happened to check on this question the next day (*before* the question was deleted) and found that my comment was gone.

My guess is that it was flagged as either "rude or offensive".  The clip had a swear word in it which I didn't think about since it was quite late at night, and that deletion reason would, I suppose, make sense.  Or it could simply have been flagged as "not constructive".

In any case, the only reason I even knew that it had any action taken upon it is that I just so happened to check back on the question the next day.  If I hadn't done that, I would have no clue.  Given that, how would it be possible for me to correct any kind of negative, harmful, or unacceptable behavior on the site?  I assume that there's some eventual limit where a user has had too many things flagged and then gets some warning, suspension or expulsion, but a user might be able to avoid that entirely if he simply knew that his content had been removed for whatever reason.

Hence the feature request: please notify users when their comments or posts are deleted, either through the Inbox or Achievements drop downs in the title bar, via e-mail, or both.

(Side note: I actually like the irony of delivering it through the Achievements drop down.  Not the appropriate place for it, but it makes me smile.)

---

**TL;DR**: If a user isn't notified that their content was abusive or otherwise inappropriate, they can't correct the behavior.  Notifying them thus helps them become more productive members of the site and reduces the generation of such content in the future.

Comment: The overly chatty people on the site will hate this with a passion.

Comment: @bluefeet I guess I was assuming that there was some limit on having comments deleted for "chattiness" at which the user gets suspended?  Or do moderators literally just deal with the same thing over and over again without taking action against the user?  If the latter is true, then yeah, I guess it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Comments get flagged and deleted, if the mods notice a user is being overly chatty in the comments or they are being flagged as rude they will be contacted by us.  Being notified that your comments are being deleted will amount to unnecessary noise, IMO.

Comment: @JeffGohlke Having comments deleted will never result in any further *automatic* action against the user in question.  If inappropriate comments are a repeated problem a moderator would *manually* contact the user, and *manually* apply a punishment if the behavior isn't corrected.

Comment: This would probably result in hundreds or thousands of new notifications per day, almost none of them being helpful in any real way. I moderate a fairly small site and if a question blows up with chatty responses I could end up deleting 20+ comments on a single question + answers

Comment: @Servy Really?  There's no automatic process for tallying how many comments a user has had deleted (especially for things like "rude or abusive")?  That makes me really, really surprised.

Comment: @JeffGohlke I said there are no automatic *actions* taken.  The actions are recorded, and the moderators presumably have tools for determining if a user has a lot of deleted comments.  The point is simply that you won't be automatically banned when a given comment is deleted, even if that deleted comment raises moderator attention somewhere.

Comment: We can actually view *all* of a user's comments, including deleted ones.

Comment: @bluefeet, "*The overly chatty people on the site will hate this with a passion.*"  True, but maybe the realization that their chatty comments are deleted will eventually train them to stop?  In that way, deletion notifications wouldn't simply be noise, right?

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378109/did-my-comment-just-disappear - In other words, a notification would've been helpful for me too.

Comment: related on meta SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117854/comment-deletion-notification

Answer (score 14):

Your point about silent deleting of comments not allowing users to learn what is and is not acceptable on the site is a valid point. But at the same time, it brings up another point: not all comment deletions are about a comment being unacceptable.

Many comments are deleted because they're no longer valid. If you ask someone to add some information to the question/answer, and they provide it, your comment isn't valid anymore. It can be deleted.

To notify users about such cleanup work is the equivalent of telling someone that their trash has been picked up. Do you really need the garbage truck to send you an e-mail every time they come by your house? Indeed, such notifications could backfire: prolific users who see lots of questions may eventually opt-out of asking for clarification entirely, just to stop being pinged for something they don't care about anymore.

Similarly, if a comment has gone into thread-mode, and a moderator comes along to correctly move it to chat, do the users need to be pinged about it? No; if they're still interested in the thread, they'll find out quickly enough. And if they aren't, then they won't care that their comments are now chat messages.

In both of these cases, there is no need to "correct any kind of negative, harmful, or unacceptable behavior on the site". So if this were to happen, it should only happen if the comment is being removed for such reasons.

But there is still one last problem. Even in cases of corrective action, there exists the possibility that users... will *complain about it.*

Look at how many users come to MSO on a daily basis to complain about *downvotes*. Look at how many users have difficulty deciding what is and is not "rude" or "unkind" or whatever. Notifying someone every time such a comment is expunged is just begging for a big bunch of complaints about these incidents.

I understand the issue. But given all of these problems, I'd prefer to leave notifications in the hands of the moderators. If a moderator sees that a person is having a lot of comments deleted for such reasons, they have the power to notify the user directly. Doing it with some automated system just has the potential to cause too many problems.

Comment: Mod messages aren't too far from suspension, though. Deliberately making the *only* feedback mechanism the one that's used just before starting to cut off site access is a bad idea. Responsible users *want* something faster and lower-key than a very formal, permanently-recorded "shape up or ship out" ultimatum.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: "*Mod messages aren't too far from suspension, though.*" How far those are from suspension sounds like a choice that individual moderators can make based on the circumstances.

Comment: @Nathan You will get at the very least a warning before a suspension. Much more likely that it is going to be more than just that. And the kind of messages that could get a user into a suspension are the a **tiny minority** of the messages that get deleted.

Comment: @yivi: Yes, that's what I said, isn't it? Other than the fact that comments leading to suspension are very rare. Which is true, but actually makes my point *more* important, since it means **there are broad classes of comment that are bad but not bad enough to ever receive any direct feedback on**. This is very inefficient and will inevitably leave lots and lots of users posting (between them) lots and lots of kinda crummy comments that aren't quite worth sending mod messages for, but that annoy tens or hundreds of thousands of users.

Comment: @Nathan So I guess you are just advocating comment deletion notification for comments that were deleted for reason of being rude or unkind, right? Those are the only ones that could lead to a suspension. That I could more or less agree with, and was already mentioned by Nicols in their answer. But still, I do not think you can post _"lots and lots"_ of suspension-worthy comments before getting suspended. If you show a pattern like that, you are going to be shown the door rather quickly.

Comment: @yivi: Nicol is specifically arguing against adding *any* further response to comments on the spectrum of "less than fully polite", leaving users with more or less the current situation, in which users with a few truly horrible comments, a lot of lousy comments, or an awful lot of lame comments will get a mod message, and everybody else gets nothing. I am arguing that this is inadequate, because of the very numerous users that specifically *don't* post anywhere near enough comments *each* to be suspended, but *do* collectively post *a lot*.

Comment: @yivi: I haven't yet advocated any particular notifications, mostly because I do agree that individual notifications on deletion would be hopelessly noisy. Instead, we could try showing *summarized stats* with links to breakdowns, like flag history but in reverse. Or we could just automate the more routine "lotsa validated flags" mod messages and make them more common, possibly adding a new category to reduce their perceived negativity further. There are lots of possibilities!

Comment: @Nathan The distinction of "horrible/lousy/lame" comments is kinda lost on me. Only users with "unkind" or "rude" messages will end up getting a mod message, and it won't get many of those. So the scenario of "lots of comments" you are describing doesn't really happen, IMO.

Comment: @yivi: I'm referring to comments that are just a little bit rude, quite possibly by mistake. Comments that are nowhere near enough to justify suspending someone for unless that's all they ever do post. The "lots of comments" I'm referring to are *not* coming from one user, but from the "lots of users" I've mentioned twice already — thousands or tens of thousands. None of them need post anywhere near enough borderline comments to justify suspension or even a clear pattern for a mod message. But the result is still tens of thousands of comment deletions with no feedback at all.

Comment: @Nathan If those thousands of users do not post enough rude messages to warrant a warning, no need to tell them anything. It's just noise.

Comment: @yivi: So … instead of merely *deleting* these comments, why would we not consider trying to *reduce their posting* by allowing users from this cohort to have some idea that they should change? If there's noise, why would we not try to reduce it? And if there's enough rudeness in those comments to warn a user for a hundred times over — but not the actual ten thousand that posted — why does this dilution suddenly mean that literally nothing at all needs to be done?

Comment: @Nathan If they are not rude or unkind, I do not think there is anything that needs to be done. If they are, they need to be flagged and deleted. The threshold for warning/banning users is quite low, I think; so the users that are not hitting it are those that are not the problem.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: "*Nicol is specifically arguing against adding any further response to comments on the spectrum of "less than fully polite",*" No, I'm not. I'm arguing against any *automatic system* for doing so. I'm arguing for letting moderators decide when and who to contact, based on the deleted comments and their comment history. And I don't understand why moderator warning messages are, or should be, only used for the most egregious cases.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I read that as basically status quo, since that is what mods currently do, so I meant "further than present" not "further than nothing". As far as mod message severity goes, they can't be used for everything, and the answer does not recommend that. So there will inevitably be a minimum threshold. In practice, that threshold is likely to be fairly high, because a mod message is a permanent black mark of sorts. This means that there is guaranteed to be a decent number of deleted rude-ish comments whose authors, collectively, have no clue they did anything wrong.

Answer (score 12):

Comments are not posts.  They are second class citizens.  A comment can be deleted not only for being rude, offensive, or spam, but for simply being obsolete, or noise and not *actively helpful*.

Your comment was not *actively helpful*.  Regardless of whether or not it was offensive, it doesn't sound like it was actually *adding value*, so a moderator is entirely within their rights to remove it.

There are no notifications because important information doesn't belong in comments in the first place.  Deleting a comment should *never* be a big deal.  If having something be deleted would be a big deal, it should be in a question or answer, not just a comment.

If a moderator finds a user to be repeatedly posting inappropriate comments, meriting deletion, to the point where it has become a problem, they can manually contact the user to explain the situation.

Comment: My point isn't that the comment shouldn't have been removed.  It should have.  It was that you can correct the behavior if you know something was wrong.

Comment: @JeffGohlke The whole situation just *isn't that important*.  It's not worth the mods getting into a debate with every single user who has a comment deleted because they *just don't matter* that much.

Comment: Fair enough.  A dont-reply e-mail notification or something in a drop down isn't an avenue for argument, though, any more than being notified that a post has been down voted.  It's not like a moderator would be pulling someone into a chat room and sitting them down for a nice talk.

Comment: @JeffGohlke You're still attaching way more importance to your comments then the system does.  *They just don't matter* that much.

Comment: @Servy: Your answer deserves at least the same up-votes, if not more than the answer by Oded. Reason: The humility of your answer is very much in tune with the humility that OP has put in the question.

Comment: `1` It's better for them to fix the problem earlier than later, so giving a warning is definitely better. `2` [so] moderators are very busy, they would more likely just suspend them. `3` On the other hand, it can be helpful to the user if they know that their comment being deleted is not a problem, so if they see their comment mysteriously disappear they don't need to worry about being suspended.

Comment: *comments just don't matter that much*.  Disagree. It's user content.  If you delete user content with no notification and no record, then it just feels like silent censorship. It flies in the face of the transparency that exists elsewhere on the site.  After 7+ years here, I just discovered this happens and suddenly I don't trust SO as much as I used to.  Based only on one moderator's opinion, my comment (which had an intended purpose) was removed and I was not notified or could learn anything about why.  And, it was only luck that I even noticed which makes me wonder how often this happens.

Comment: After 10,000 answers and 30,000 comments, now I suddenly wonder what else is silently deleted on SO.  And, I totally agree with the OP that deleting something with no rationale and no notification is like sending a kid to the corner for a timeout and not telling them why.  It's unlikely to improve future behavior and will surely make the subject mad.  The "importance" or "value" of comments is in the eye of the beholder.  SO, can't tell us that our comments don't matter.  That's for us to determine how much they matter to us.

Comment: @Servy If the situation "isn't that important" then the mods shouldn't be pissing on people by deleting their comments in the first place. On the other hand, if the comments are so harmful as to warrant silent nuking then, apparently their existence _was_ important enough, and therefore the author should be notified so that they can improve in the future. Otherwise this is a massive contradiction.

Answer (score 8):

You should expect comments to get deleted.

If they are oh-so-important, they should get rolled into the post they are commenting on. At which point they are obsolete.

Comments exist in order to clarify/suggest fixes to the post - **not** for discussion.

Comment: My point isn't that the comment shouldn't have been removed.  It should have.  It was that you can correct the behavior if you know something was wrong.

Comment: @Jeff - sometimes the behaviour is fine. But if the OP followed up on a suggestion of a comment, that comment is obsolete. And should go. Why notify you about comments. Your request gives comments more importance than we are willing to give them.

Comment: I don't think my contributions here are oh-so-important, but, gosh, is this really the posture you want to assume toward your users? "Oh, isn't that cute, *somebody* thinks they're oh-so-important." I'd like to know when my contributions are deleted. Yes, whether you think they're important or not. Yes, whether you think I sure care or not. I'd still like to know.

Comment: And, yes, partly so I can correct bad behavior. And partly just because a system that doesn't do this is just sort of a rude system that doesn't care about its users.

Comment: @lwburk - I am talking about comments, not users. The content, not the contributor.

Comment: @lwburk - I see. You are thinking of [so] as a social site. We don't think the same - our focus is on content, not people.

Comment: No, I get that. Or I get that you think that. But your contributors are people, so it is about people whether you like it or not.

Comment: @Oded Perhaps your answer could clarify who should do the rolling of comments into posts, then, I assume, make this comment obsolete. Is there an assumption at SO that a poster will constantly massage a post to the point of removing all comments?

Comment: @ASTPace - um. Anyone can do that. The commenter. The post OP. Another interested user (anonymous or not). That's why we have suggested edits and the edit privilege.

Comment: "*If [comments] are oh-so-important, they should get rolled into the post they are commenting on.*"  This is great in theory, but it does not happen very consistently.  I often encounter answers that have a critical addition or criticism as a highly upvoted comment that has not been integrated into the answer.

Comment: @kdb and you have the power to do so. Why not exercise it?

Comment: I do, and so do others.  The point is that integration doesn't happen instantly, so the content of a valuable comment is a first class citizen until it is integrated.  I don't disagree with you.  I just want to clarify that, at least temporarily, comments can be just as valuable as an answer

Comment: @Oded may I assume that I won't get in any kind of trouble when my comments are deleted for any reason, as long as I'm not blatantly out of line?

Comment: @Stijn - that certainly should be the case. Deleting comments should have no penalty, unless the comment itself would be (as you put it) blatantly out of line (and therefore cause for penalty all by itself).

Comment: I don't get this "not for discussion" why is there "Move this to discussion" option available after couple of comments?

Comment: @Kyslik - people still want to discuss things. So, instead of having tha happen in comments, they can move them to chat, which is a much better medium for discussion.

Comment: I am still in the impression that stackexchange creators meant to use comments for *more* than just suggest to edits. Why is there a tag feature @Oded? Like how many % of people’s comments are: “Hey @Oded I think OP should add more info about...” it just weird or I don’t have the whole picture, to be frank I never bothered to read how to ask/answer/comment (if such exists) I just *copied* behaviour of higher rep. people. Anyway thank you for answering my previous answer.

Comment: @Kyslik Because the comments are not for discussion. So if people are having a discussion, that option offers the ability to _move_ the discussion from the wrong place to the proper place.

Comment: "Comments are not for discussion", while great in theory, entirely breaks down in practice. Someone comments "I think answer should include X", someone replies "that makes no sense because Y". I think that counts as a discussion, even if very short. But it's a discussion about *improving the post*.

Answer (score 4):

> If a user isn't notified that their content was abusive or otherwise inappropriate, they can't correct the behaviour

I think this is best point on this feature-request. But the problem is that *rude* and *unkind* comments are still a very tiny minority of the comments that are deleted. Comments are deleted all the time and **should** be deleted all the time.

Providing notifications for **all** comment deletions when it could be potentially useful for only a very small fraction of these events wouldn't be smart. The downsides would drown the potential upsides.

Even if we only sent notification of deleted messages for *rude* or *unkind* messages, the downsides are still very likely be much more than the benefits. Each user being able to react to each deletion would get extremely noisy very quickly. For moderators. Here in meta. We'd get posts about this every day. We already get quite a few of these even now that comment deletion flies under the radar.

As an alternative, following the spirit of this question, I'd propose a solution that's less granular, but that still allows users to be more or less aware of how do they stand in regards to their behaviour in comments without the need of further moderator intervention.

### The *Rude-o-meter<sup><sub>TM</sub></sup>*

Each user could have a *Rude-o-meter<sup><sub>TM</sub></sup>*, that would start in green for all users. As more *rude* or *unkind* messages are deleted, the *Rude-o-meter<sup><sub>TM</sub></sup>* would start getting darker (let's imagine a typical green-yellow-orange-red scale).

- If you are green, everybody is happy.
- If you are yellow, well, you are not part of the solution, but it is not yet time to get really worried. You **know** that some of your comments were deleted for being generally unwelcoming, and that a change of tack would be advisable. No need to know exactly which comments, nor exactly how many (you should be more or less aware, and if not it's not important, the important thing is that you know that a change is warranted).
- If you are orange, it's worrying time. By this time you would have normally gotten a mod-warning, although the *Rude-o-meter<sup><sub>TM</sub></sup>* would provide this kind of notification as a standard feature. It's built this way. You have been naughty and the next stop is suspension time.
- If you are red, you are suspended. Hopefully, the whole process is automatic so the suspensions would escalate. First one X weeks, second one 2X weeks, third time 4X weeks, etc.

This would provide some feedback on comment deletion opening an avenue for users to know they have to do better when communicating with other users, without increasing the noise level, and hopefully reducing a tiny bit moderator workload since *Rude-o-meter<sup><sub>TM</sub></sup>* notifications could replace mod-warnings in many cases, and hopefully, the whole system would make some users change their attitude without further mod intervention.

#### More implementation details

- The *Rude-o-meter<sup><sub>TM</sub></sup>* should only consider comment deletions in the last 12 months. So your *Rude-o-meter<sup><sub>TM</sub></sup>* situation would automatically better if you start behaving better as time goes on.
- Although the system feeds from comments deletion, it shouldn't be calculated directly from deleted comments, but from a separate point system. E.g. each time, you get an *unwelcoming* comment deleted, you get a *Rude-o-meter<sup><sub>TM</sub></sup>* point.
- On coming back from the first suspension the user should "recover" enough points for them to go back to "yellow". Following suspensions should drop the user back to "orange".
- The specific point thresholds of the *Rude-o-meter<sup><sub>TM</sub></sup>* should be kept secret and could be changed and tuned if necessary.

<sub>Rude-o-meter it is not an actual registered trade-mark.</sub>

Comment: This is a nice idea, perhaps it should be a feature request on its own. But what about helpful comments, shouldn't they be calculated to improve the rude-o-meter? 5 rude out of 6 in a year is different than 5 rude out of 1000 in the same period.

Comment: I like this idea but I don't think this should _replace_ mod-warnings. Personally I have autism and I can't tell it when I did something rude, you basicly have to slap a comment in my face stating _This is rude, don't do it again_ for me to understand it. But this sounds like a great addition (even for me because it gives me a warning so I can ask for advice on what I'm doing)

Comment: @user000001It should probably be a FR on its own, you are right. But I begun writing and got carried away. And in a short bit I'm going away on holidays mostly off-grid, so I am not sure I'll be able to create the correct post for a few days. Regarding your other point: Helpful comments do not make you _less_ rude, nor less likely to be suspended. These are not taken into account today, and should not be taken into account into the future. Being helpful does not give your the right to be rude or unkind.

Comment: @AndréKool the Rude-o-Meter should not completely replace our dear mods, nor it could. _Yet_. So standard mod messages could be sent as well, if needed. The idea would be to give more information about comment deletions in a way that's both useful and not noisy.

Comment: Would the rude-o-meter be visible to other end-users?

Comment: I don’t think it should. It’s solely to help the rude-o-meter owner. @kevin

Comment: That's a good idea, btw, something like a sender reputation implemented by mailing service providers ( at least I know SES does do that ). As an addition, it should probably degrade over time ( as heated discussions tend to generate offensive comments, and once everyone cools off, there is little or no point in counting them against the user .)

Answer (score -4):

With the recent enhancements to flagging of comments, it appears that more comments are getting flagged and the mods are responding by deleting more comments.  This seems to be happening more now than it used to.

When those comments are deleted by a mod, there is no notification to the author and no history to see what happened or why it happened.

This has the following downsides:

1. The author has no chance to learn how to better use the site or what they did wrong with their comment.  My analogy is it's kind of like sending a four-year-old to sit in the corner for 15 minutes, but not telling them why.  It has little chance of modifying behavior for the better and is guaranteed to make them mad.  Just like we know that's not a good way to parent, that's also not a good way to moderate.
2. If the author somehow discovers that their content was deleted without any notification or history, they will wonder what happened, wonder what else they wrote might have been silently deleted and begin to question the whole transparency of SO which is otherwise very good (all of those happened to me when my comment was silently deleted).
3. The whole notion that you should just "expect comments to be deleted" does not fit with the overall nature of SO.  Comments are the only way we have to communicate with other users on the site (outside of writing an answer).  Sure, if you clearly violate terms of service, then certainly content can be deleted, but even then the author should be notified and be given some idea why (even if it's just tagged with a broad category).  If a mod can't even take the time to click one broad area choice for why it's being deleted and the SO system can't notify them that their content was deleted and communicate that broad category of reason, then the system is really not working to the benefit of everyone.
4. I am now seeing comments get deleted because they "might" trigger an off-topic or undesirable discussion.  IMO, that's not right.  Comments should get deleted when they do go in a wrong direction, not because they might go in a wrong direction.

*If you want Stack Overflow to continue with its excellent architecture of transparency, want users to learn from their mistakes and improve their behavior, want users to continue to trust the content on Stack Overflow, then users need to be notified anytime one of their comments is deleted with at least a broad reason for why.*

Silently deleting user content is a slippery slope that I think we all want Stack Overflow to stay far away from.

Comment: Comments are temporal.  They should only exist as a whisper on the wind.  If a comment is removed it should be a non-event.  We've mutated comments to be the beast they are today by believing that there's more weight and dignity attached to them than there actually is.

Comment: `"My analogy is it's kind of like sending a four year old to sit in the corner for 15 minutes, but not telling them why."`  Except nobody goes in the corner for deleted comments. Ever. There is literally no problem with having a no longer needed comment deleted, there are problems with *posting abusive comments*. Moderators will (I think, it never happened to me but it's how it's documented) contact users that need to be contacted.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - The point is that you feel like your content got whacked (which it did) and you don't know why and it was only accidental that you even found out.  It does nothing to influence behavior and is likely to make the author mad.  There could be very different outcomes if you're notified and given a reason.  You could learn and adapt and improve your use of the site.

Comment: I assume you mean all the "Why was my answer downvoted?" comments? though, i would like to be notified too when my comments are deleted.

Comment: @Makoto - Sorry, but stack overflow doesn't get to tell people how they should feel when their comments are removed.  That's up to the authors to decide how they feel.  Comments are part of the vibrancy of the site and are extremely necessary and we all know the site would be a lot less useful if all comments expired in 15 minutes.  So, saying they are all temporal is really just useless.  They are a very important part of the site (I've posted 30,000 of them).

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, I do feel that as well when I see my bad puns get deleted, and other comments where I am a bit more heavy handed towards another user. I don't know, I think I understand your point, and I felt we'd need notifications in the past, but at some point, I started to simply feel that there would be so much noise and retaliation if we'd get notifications. Image all the "oh yeah so you bast*** flagged my comments?! How dare you let me downvote your shit"...

Comment: That is honestly an unfortunate shortcoming of the system.  Comments cannot be indexed, searched on, favorited, or *anything* like that, whereas questions and answers enjoy this privilege.  You cannot even see deleted comments, even with rep as high as yours (right now).  The only way we can stop acting like comments are more important than they  are is if we start instilling reality - **they're temporal**.  They can go away at any time.  Do not treat them any differently than simply a way to request additional feedback from the OP.  (Meta is an exception.)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - If you're getting notification overflow because of lots of deleted comments, then you would need to learn from that and change your behavior.  That's a perfect example of how notifications would improve things.  Right now, you might never even know you were getting lots of comments deleted so would have no reason to change behavior.

Comment: @Makoto - That's all a bit overly simplistic.  You must know as well as I do that there are hundreds of legitimate uses for comments beyond just asking the OP for clarification on the original question.  They are how we communicate with people involved in a particular Q&A.  For example, I regularly use comments to help educate newbie users on the better ways of stackoverflow, not only in the interest of that particular question, but in the interest of teaching them how to better use stackoverflow.  Saying comments are temporal and we should all just expect them to disappear is just an excuse.

Comment: Honestly, no, it means that the system is broken and *has* been broken for a long time if one believes that comments are the right way to mentor.  That doesn't scale and this is prime reason why - comments aren't meant to live for very long.  Another solution has to be put in place, but let's not let the lack of a solution justify abuse of *another* service.

Comment: @Makoto - *Shortcoming of the system*.  We should separate out in this discussion what we all think the best and most useful experience would be from the implementation difficulties because of the current architecture.  Those are two completely separate topics.  As a career software developer, I understand that actually deciding to prioritize and implement something has to take into account both aspects (how desirable the feature is AND how difficult it is to implement) but those are two separate discussions.  It would likely be better here for us to focus on the former.

Comment: I believe I have focused on the shortcoming of the system.  I've stated that it's undesirable at best to use another functionality meant for something else to cover in this gap.  I'll happily leave it there.

Comment: @Makoto - So, I should stop all mentoring comments?  I should stop explaining why pasting links to images of code is not the right way to do things?  I should stop explaining why only external links to code needed to understand the question is not the right way to do things.  I should stop teaching people how to debug their own code better before they come to stack overflow so they can both collect better info on the current problem and next time arrive here with more appropriate information about the problem to start with?  Really?  This all sounds like you don't see the same posts I do.

Comment: @jfriend00 Are those comments actually being deleted?

Comment: Yes - you *should* stop.  Just close the question.  The Help Center should cover these circumstances.  If it doesn't, advocate for *that* to get updated so you don't have to consistently explain the same thing to the same group of people time and time again.

Comment: @KevinB - I'm responding to Makoto's suggestion that those shouldn't be be put into comments.  Honestly, I don't know what is and isn't being deleted.  There's no notification of a deleted comment or any way to look at what's been deleted, so I don't really know what does or doesn't get deleted.  After noticing (quite accidentally) that some comments of a different type were getting deleted, I now don't quite know what to trust.

Comment: @Makoto - That's extremely unfriendly and is part of SO's really, really bad reputation for new users.  If you just whack their question closed within minutes of posting with no effort to teach them what they did wrong and no opportunity for them to fix their question before it gets closed, they just walk away feeling like this is an abusive, non-helpful place.  I think we should be better than that and I think that many times I succeed.  The whole notion that they can edit it after it gets closed and it will be eligible for reopening is hogwash.  Questions almost never get reopened.

Comment: Welcome to what has been the last six or so months of Meta discussion.  If you really, really, *really* think that this is a deficiency, you should advocate for changes in the ***system***.  Your advice and guidance is genuinely being lost in the wind.  I don't think you quite get this - I'm on your side here.  I just disagree with your methodology.

Comment: @Makoto - How is it not better for everyone to communicate with the person who wrote the question, help them understand what they need to do to fix their question and allow them some time to actually edit it and fix it.  Why should you just whack it closed and expect some help center reference to lead them to a good experience?

Comment: @Makoto - That's what I'm doing here.  I'm advocating for a change to the system.  It's not a very pleasant or productive process, but that's what I'm trying to do here.  If you think my advice to newbie posters in comments is always being lost in the wind, you're wrong.  They learn how to form a good stack overflow question and they get an answer.  I do this all the time.  If it didn't usually work, I wouldn't keep doing it.  Sure, it doesn't always work and in those cases, I end up voting to close the question.  But, it works lots of the time - if it didn't I wouldn't keep doing it.

Comment: I don't think mods are going around approving comment flags on useful comments such as the ones you're mentioning. I've certainly had a few flags on noisy "welcoming" comments declined recently. but comments that are no longer useful almost always get deleted with little effort.

Comment: can i not respond to the sub discussion?

Comment: @KevinB - You can.  I wasn't ever saying that those type of comments are what is getting deleted.  The sub-discussion about those type of comments popped up when Makoto said that those aren't even supposed to be put in comments at all which seemed ridiculous to me because that form of communication is required to make SO work well and there is no other way to communicate.

Comment: he's not wrong, that such comments aren't necessary, that the close reasons *should* be enough to instruct the user how to improve their question. But neither are you, in that such comments *can* help those who are willing to listen. But we both know that.

Comment: @KevinB - You simply can't have it both ways.  You either believe we should communicate with newbies (comments is the only way to do that) to explain things to them and educate them on the ways of SO or you believe comments should never be used for such communication so the only thing you possibly to is just whack the question with downvotes and closevotes and the consequence is a pretty horrible experience for many newbies (SO is famous for that bad experience already).  Pick one.  Can't have both.  I've seen great success with such communication in comments so that's what I do.

Comment: Both are valid options.

Comment: @KevinB - So you think it's a good thing for SO to just whack newbie questions with downvotes and closevotes and no communication?  Do you think that's best for the SO community?  Best for SO's growth with new users?  Best for OS's reputation?  You really can't have it both ways.

Comment: Neither opinion is being strictly enforced by the SO team. Until one is chosen, or the other outlawed, neither of you are wrong.

Comment: And, yes, i think people who post low quality content should receive downvotes. Lots of them. Newbies included.

Comment: @KevinB - Geez.  Offer an opinion on which is better.  This isn't a legal argument, it's a discussion about which is better for SO.  You're adding no value to the discussion by saying either is valid and offering no opinion.

Comment: I like giving users a helping hand when they need it. But i'm not going to forgo using my votes while i'm doing so.

Comment: @jfriend00: "*Silently deleting user content is a slippery slope that I think we all want Stack Overflow to stay far away from.*" Considering that comments have been deleted for *years* now, and we haven't fallen into that "slippery slope", maybe that's not a particular danger.

Comment: @NicolBolas - It appears to be happening a more often now (making it a bigger issue), perhaps due to comment flag UI changes or different moderator behavior.  Do you really think that silent deletion with no activity log and the lack of transparency that that causes is a desirable feature of SO?