# Do I get notified when someone deletes my comment?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

Short question: I think someone deleted a comment I made on a question I asked. Do I get notified about that deletion?

This most definetly is a duplicate, but I did not find anything using the search here on meta.

Comment: The comment was flagged, it wasn't really a constructive comment (calling a community grumpy really doesn't help improve the discourse, does it?), so a moderator deleted it.

Comment: :-) yeah I know... but how do you? This is spooky...

Comment: I'm an elected community moderator, I can see deleted comments. All I had to do was look at your most recent question to find it.

Comment: follow-up-question: a moderator can just click on my name and see all the mess I made? I better behave now! :-)

Comment: Yes, moderators can see everything you do on this site, including deleted content.

Comment: Related: [Please notify users when their comment is deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255137/please-notify-users-when-their-comment-is-deleted)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you don't.

You don't get notified when someone deletes your answer either, and comments are no different.

Comment: it was a comment on my own question, I did not even think they could be deleted

Comment: @TobiasGassmann: *all* comments are subject to deletion. Comments are second-rate citizens, and should be viewed as temporary.

Comment: hmm.. was my question concerning notifications on deleted comments that bad? (minus 3 Overall Score on my question, versus 9 Upvotes on the answer) Maybe I did not fully understand the scope of Meta?

Comment: @TobiasGassmann I was wondering that too. It seems to be a common thing. I'm not sure but I think on meta a down vote can simply be disagreement. Your question is perfectly fine, maybe a tad misleading "do" in title "should" in question.

Comment: @TobiasGassmann: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites

Comment: @MartijnPieters `are second-rate citizens` unless you go off the rails, and tell a moderator to eat shit, then your comments will get treated as "first-rate citizen" as they deserve and you will face the consequences of your action - though without notification I will never know, that someone was offended by my comment and it got deleted [don't take my "eat shit" personal, just wanted to make a point, that if comments get deleted its for a reason, but without notification I will never know the reason, and may continue my lose tongue, but I may be "charged" as if comments aren't second-rate]

Comment: @RandRandom: don't worry, if that happens more than a few times we'll be in touch with you to let you know via a moderator private message.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - totally misses my point… as I tried to point out getting notified about deleted comments prior to a moderation interaction to give users the chance to reflect about their deleted comments… once a mod  needs to PM me, its to late and I can already face consequences, consequences about stuff I never even knew I did wrong in the first place because I never got notified….

Comment: @RandRandom: who said anything about _consequences_? A moderator message explaining how the site works or why your comments needed to be deleted on the grounds of CoC issues is *just a message*. Note that we delete **tens of thousands of comments every day**, notifying you of comments that have been deleted will quickly get very very old.

Answer (score 0):

Why should you get notified, there's nothing you can do about it. If you recreated it, it would only have to be deleted again presumably for the same reason it was deleted in the first place and that would just be more mod-work for nothing.

The principle here is that you only get notified when you might need to do something about it. E.g. someone has commented on your post, so you might need to review said post in order to clarify it.

Comment: Of course if a comment gets removed because it violates the "be nice" policy and one insists on recreating them - that's one way to pretty much guarantee receiving a "notification"...

Comment: The first thing you need to "do" when a comment is deleted is figure out *why* it was deleted so you can avoid the same in the future.  No notification mean no improvement.

Comment: Can only agree with @Daniel without ever knowing something got deleted, why should you know you did something wrong in the first place? and when you somehow notice "hey my stuff is gone", you have no clue what the reason for the action was, so learning progress is zero, and you will continue your day as if nothing happened.