# Replace flag icon with something more appropriate

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface, comment-flags

I often had it that some of my comments went away without notice, though they weren't bad in any way (I think).

Now I got a hint of what might have happened: One of the newbies told me that he used the flag icon to mark the comment as "Okay, I understood and did according action". Quite understandable.

Now, the intention of the flag is more a "red flag" but that does not seem to be obvious enough.

How about replacing it with something like a STOP sign?

Comment: I guess they marked it as "No longer needed"? That's perfectly fine when they did what you requested (editing, ...)

Comment: "though they weren't bad in any way" - comments don't have to bad to be removed. A user who acts on one of your comments and then flags it as "no longer needed" is using the flag system as it is intended.

Comment: But now a mod needs to handle it. And they are likely to disagree with the flag. So the comment wont be deleted. What exactly raising that flag proves?

Comment: Flagging isn't just for, "Hey, this is bad, somebody needs to do something about it."  It's to bring it to a mod's attention that it should be deleted.  Sometimes, it just isn't needed anymore.  That doesn't mean the commentor should be punished for it.  It's just a bit of cleanup.

Comment: can you provide a link to the post where the comment was? I can't find the comment

Comment: @Yvette: [This is it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577698/static-list-of-objects-out-class-in-kotlin). Ironically, it will look familiar. :-)

Answer (score 12):

It is quite hard to flag as "no longer needed" by a misclick.

It requires first clicking on the flag, and then selecting an option from a dialog where no value is selected by default and "no longer needed" is the **third** option:

> [image]

If they were flagging comments by accident on any other category, it would be fairly obvious for the handling mod that that the flag didn't apply and they wouldn't honour it.

I believe the hypothesis that users are flagging these comments by mistake because of the "flag" icon is incorrect. While it's not impossible, it requires a pretty determined flag a comment in error.

And even then, most flags are reviewed by a mod. Unless multiple users are flagging your comment as NLN, which I think can trigger comment auto-deletion. But if that happens, it is even less likely the flagging happened by mistake.

So most of these disappearing comments were flagged correctly, and that's the reason they were deleted

Changing the icon to something different from a **flag** would make **flagging** more confusing.

Comments are deleted all the time. The most common reason is that the comment is deemed obsolete. It's usually advisable to treat comments as ephemeral, and to post anything you think of lasting value in an actual post (question or answer).

Comment: @ThomasKilian Huh. I've flagged over 1.200 comments. Almost all of them as "no longer needed". This means nothing, really, we all moderate what we're comfortable with. You just might be not familiar with comment flagging, but that doesn't mean there is something wrong with it.

Comment: It is possible that a single user flagging a comment could cause it to be deleted with no moderator intervention/review required. There are a set of regular expressions that, if they match certain key words or phrases in the comment, will cause the comment to be insta-deleted by the flagger (the flagger actually is given credit for deletion in the mod UI). I can’t list all the patterns (at least in part because I don’t know them), but “thank you” is definitely one, at least for short comments, designed to make obviously noisy comments easy to dispose of. Expletives are another match category.

Comment: @Thomas I understand how having your comments removed without notice can seem odd, or even broken. Note first that we cannot notify everyone each time a comment is deleted, as it’s not unusual for moderators to delete thousands of comments per day across the site. That’s too much noise in notifications, and notifying about things when you don’t need to take any action is an anti-pattern. If the comments were deleted because you were doing something wrong (like being rude), a moderator would contact you privately to inform you of this.

Comment: Second, I think it would help if you better understood how we view comments here. They’re seen as very temporary, somewhat like post-it notes, suggesting improvements or asking for clarifications on a post. Once those changes are made, it’s common for users to flag these comments as “no longer needed” or “obsolete”, and moderators to clean them up. The focus here is on questions and answers. Comments are third-class citizens indeed, and they only exist at all as a practical concession. Anything important or lasting should be put into an answer. (Do as I say, not as I do, of course ;-))

Comment: @ThomasKilian See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255137/please-notify-users-when-their-comment-is-deleted). Pretty sure there are others.

Comment: Say you got notified of a deleted comment... What would you do? What would you gain? @ThomasKilian

Comment: Moré often than not users would repost the deleted comment. Or argue against the deletion. Or simply escalate matters. To much noise for something that’s of secondary importance for the site.

Comment: Since “it depends on the comment and the cause”, I believe that at least in some cases my previous comment would apply. I believe individual comment deletion notification would be a terrible idea.

Comment: I would be supremely annoyed if I got a ping when my comments were deleted. I don't know how many get deleted, but it ought to be quite a few across different sites. A lot of comments I write are specifically intended as temporary, e.g ones like "This answer could benefit from elaborating on X because of Y" if someone gets rid of those for me, that's saving me from deleting them later, and a ping would negate that.

Comment: @Magisch In a now deleted comment, the OP was defending an _optional setting_ to receive notifications about comment deletions. So that would deal with the obvious annoyance to all of us who **don't want** to receive notifications. But it wouldn't solve the issue of how annoying users who would opt-in to receive these notifications could become for the rest of the site.