# Deleted comments on unresolved question

Tags: discussion

My unresolved [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68916663/changing-a-checkboxs-font-attribute-strikethrough-from-a-specific-modul-does) had all comments deleted. Specifically one of the lasts comments stated that a user was going to post again at a later time. Now that the comments are deleted, I have no way of checking if he posted again or to notify him again.

Also I haven't transferred all information from the comments into my question.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening in the future? And why did they get deleted in the first place? Maybe I don't see the bigger picture here (a good reason for the deletion), but this is very frustrating. Some enlightenment would be appreciated.

Comment: "Now that the comments are deleted, I have no way of checking if he posted again or to notify him again." OP's are notified about new answers.

Comment: As for why they were deleted, they were likely flagged as no longer required or conversational, and so deleted.

Comment: If you want to preserve anything, take a screen dump. Comment, posts, users can all go missing.

Comment: SO is a questions and answers site. Comments are second-class citizens, a later addition to make people stop asking for clarification in answers. Important information should be stored in questions or answers.

Comment: or use a userscript - there are a bunch of those built by the community on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/). In general, comments do not live very long. And yes, the rules and community consensus on this are mostly hidden in various Meta posts where you are now.

Comment: @JeanneDark "OP's are notified about new answers" if it was an answer yes, but not if he just commented again, then this new comment got deleted before I had the chance to read it.

Comment: @JeanneDark "Important information should be stored in questions or answers.", this (as I stated in my question) requires the information to be transferred from the comment to the question. I didn't get a chance to do that since the comments got deleted "right away" or at least before I had a chance to finish.

Comment: "if it was an answer yes, but not if he just commented again" Then the problem is not that comments are being deleted, but that they are not writing an answer and answer in a comment instead.

Comment: "requires the information to be transferred from the comment to the question" Not sure I can follow you there. If the comments were asking for clarification and you know what's needed, you can update your question regardless of the presence of those comments. If the info from the comments forms an answer, it shouldn't be edited into the question. Questions should be questions, answers answers. It's all about them on SO.

Comment: @JeanneDark Sorry, if I was unclear, my point is that I was in the process of transferring the information from the comments into more "permanent posts" (the question and/or self-answer). But the comments got deleted before I could finish.

Comment: *"but not if he just commented again"* if they add a comment to your question you will always get a notification too. So your point is moot here; if they comment or answer you *do* get notified.

Comment: If you _**really**_ think you need the information that was in the comment, flag your post for moderator attention and explain that to them with great details. Mods can see deleted comments. Those comments might have been deleted for a good reason though, so **please don't flag** unless you know they were useful comments. You don't want to waste volunteering mods' time for no good reason. Please also note that custom flags take time to process, so be patient.

Comment: @41686d6564 that's exactly my point, now that the comments are gone, I can not check any more if there were any useful comments left. But I just accepted that comments get deleted for whatever reason. I still don't see the benefit of a quick deletion of (all) comments but this seems to be expected judging by -8 score, oh well...

Comment: @Larnu Not sure how a notification should help me if the comments I'm being notified about are already deleted?!

Comment: So you're saying the comments are being posted and deleted before you read them, @Albin ? Then how did you know they ever existed..?

Comment: @Larnu - the notification stays in the inbox even if the comment is deleted in the by the time the user opened their inbox - it is even possible to read some of the text. Clicking on one simply takes you to the parent post.

Comment: @OlegValter this, in my experience, has been hit or miss. They are [the notification] removed after a time. But if the OP does see the notification they could read it all on their inbox. However, if the comment has since been deleted it clearly held no value, so not being able to read it isn't an issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please notify users when their comment is deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255137/please-notify-users-when-their-comment-is-deleted)

Comment: @StephenRauch thank for the link, unfortunately no, it doesn't.

Comment: @OlegValter thanks for your suggestion with the user script, that's the kind of solution I was looking for. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: Nah, there's nothing new in my comment - Stack Apps is a small site on the network and is relatively obscure as a result, so I try to raise awareness when I can given that it houses quality-of-life scripts/extensions/bots for involved users.

Comment: @Larnu not sure about miss - I can't recall any instance of notifications for deleted comments being removed after a period of time (needs some field testing, though). Was only noting that the OP could know about the comments deleted prior to being read via their inbox notifications.

Comment: I see if *all* the time, @OlegValter . I get a notification, and then it's gone later on, as the comment is deleted.

Comment: @Larnu interesting - need to check that just out of curiosity. I am not sure why would the notification self-destruct, but with SE, everything's possible...

Comment: @Larnu true, notifications about comments that got deleted seem to be deleted as well, unless I looked in the wrong place. So if there was a comment I haven't read it's deleted know anyway including the notification. In my view that's one more reason not to delete comments so quickly, but that's just my personal opinion, and as I said, I'm not trying to change anything here. Anyway since Oleg's answered my main question (on how to avoid this), I'm fine. Thanks to all of you for your participation!

Answer (score 3):

Forget about the disappearing comments as they are considered second-class citizens on this site, the reasons as pointed out in the comments you're seeing above, and so their importance *and stability* are limited, as you're currently finding out.

The *main* issue, the *only* issue, that you should focus on is that your question is currently unanswered, and if you strongly desire a high-quality answer and want one soon, then you should increase the question's visibility and importance by placing a bounty on the question.

Also, it never hurts to ask yourself if and how you can edit your question so that it is easier to answer.  Jon Skeet's ["Stack Overflow question checklist"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648) can help you with tips on how to improve questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess having 277k reputation makes it easy to place a bounty, with 633 reputation I don't consider that being an option for me yet. Hopefully some time in the future. I understand that comments are not considered important (even before I posted this question), but I still fail to see any benefit in deleting them after such a short time (especially if they still benefit the OP). However I'm not trying to change the way things are done here, so I'll just follow Oleg Valter's advice and will implement a back of my own since this is the only way of "preventing deletion".

Comment: Regarding *"I guess having 277k reputation makes it easy to place a bounty, with 633 reputation I don't consider that being an option for me yet."* -- well, why not? What are you going to do with your 633 unicorn points? What can I do with my 277K unicorn points? Not a darn thing, other than use it for bounties if needed. Shoot, by spending only 40 of your points, you'd get a *lot* of activity and answers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels isn't [50 points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/786798) the minimum? But yeah, bounties are probably among the best ways of spending rep (unless one sets their eyes on getting more curation priviliges fast - in which case hesitation is understandable)

Comment: @OlegValter ah yes, you're right. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @OlegValter: Shoot. Let's see what 50 points can do...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels first of all thanks for setting the bounty. Hopefully something will come out of it. In regards to "why not", well it was the decision I felt most comfortable with, regarding various aspects (the the privilege thing Oleg pointed out is one of them, but not the only one), call it a gut feeling if you will. As I said, I think this will change with time... thanks again.